# Docusign: radio buttons selection doesn't work as expected

Tags: apex, integration, docusign

I am generating anchor tabs via salesfore (for radio button group of 2 radio buttons), and I have two anchor tabs named;

1. /candidate_amccb1/
2. /candidate_amccb2/

Once I click on the particular button to generate the doccusign document it generates the document with
the relevant custom fields (anchor tabs)

Once I sent the document to recipient when the recipient try to select a radio button, it always select the other button of the group of 2;

> eg: Radio group has two radio buttons 'A' and 'B'
>
> when you try to select 'A' it will select 'B' and when you try 'B' it
>   will select 'A'.

Anyone has an idea about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the required property of the Radio Button.On Radio Button u will find edit properties option in that there is a formating properties option .From there u can uncheck the required checkbox.